# Manage two Entity Framework models with same table name

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Using an Database first approch, I have imported into my project (without saving the connection info into the app.config file) two schemas into two different folders: `AModel/AModel.edmx` and `BModel/BModel.edmx`. In this two schema there are only two tables with the same name (but different columns name).

I wrote this singleton class to manage the connection:

```
using System;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using SynchronizeDatabase.Properties;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;

using AEntities = SynchronizeDatabase.AModel.Entities;
using BEntities = SynchronizeDatabase.BModel.Entities;

namespace SynchronizeDatabase.Tools
{
    class DBInstance
    {
        private static volatile DBInstance _instance;
        private static readonly object _padLock = new object();

        private readonly OleDbConnection _accessConnection;
        private readonly Lazy<AEntities> _lazyContextA;
        private readonly Lazy<BEntities> _lazyContextB;

        private DBInstance()
        {
            _accessConnection = new OleDbConnection(Settings.Default.ACCESS_PATH);
            _lazyContextA = new Lazy<AEntities>(() => new AEntities(BuildConnectionString(Settings.Default.A_DB_NAME)));
            _lazyContextB = new Lazy<BEntities>(() => new BEntities(BuildConnectionString(Settings.Default.B_DB_NAME)));
        }

        public static DBInstance Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    lock (_padLock)
                    {
                        if (_instance == null)
                        {
                            _instance = new DBInstance();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }

        public OleDbConnection AccessConnection => _accessConnection;
        public AEntities AContext => _lazyContextA.Value;
        public BEntities BContext => _lazyContextB.Value;

        private string BuildConnectionString(string name)
        {
            Settings settings = Settings.Default;
            string provider = $"data source={settings.DB_HOST};" +
                              $"initial catalog={name};" +
                              $"persist security info=True;" +
                              $"{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.DB_USER) ? $"user id={settings.DB_USER};password={settings.DB_PASSWORD};" : "Integrated Security=True;")}";

            string metadata = $"res://*/{name}Model.{name}Model.csdl|res://*/{name}Model.{name}Model.ssdl|res://*/{name}Model.{name}Model.msl";


            return new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient",
                ProviderConnectionString = provider + "MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;",
                Metadata = metadata,
            }.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to apply the `Count()` linq method to count the rows into one table i have this exception:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: 'Invalid schema specified.
> Errors: The mapping of the CLR type to the EDM type is ambiguous
> because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'TableA'. CLR type found
> earlier

I change the `.edmx` file from: `<EntityType Name="PlasticComponent">` to `<EntityType Name="PlasticComponent" customannotation:ClrType="CaleffiCodeModel.PlasticComponent">` but the problem persit

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods Because they are two different databases in all respects but have some tables that have the same name.

Comment: Ah, Ok ... that makes some sense now.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods Perfect ;) Can you give me a tips to solve the problem?

Comment: I am afraid not. Everything I came up with so far turns back on me, because I only know Code-First and doesn't help in DB-First. But I'll +1 - I'd really like to know how that is solved.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods Thanks for the support ;) I hope to have an answer soon

Comment: Can you not save the connection and use DB entities separately so there is no ambiguity?

Then you can specify whether it is AEntities or BEntities.

Comment: Also, you can create stored procedures in each of the database (since you are using DB first) and call them instead. Just name them differently.

Comment: @CSharp I don't save the connection into the ```app.config``` so the user can set the connection param without recompile the solution.  But I just try with saving the connection information and the problem persist

Comment: I would at least consider migrating to Code-First. My impression is that Code-first seem to be the most popular and promoted style, with edmx not even supported in EF Core. I don't see any reason why duplicate table names should be a problem in Code-First as long as the dbContext is different, but I'm not an EF expert, so take what I say with a grain of salt.

Comment: Could you please also add the linq code? You might have to specify dbInstance there like: dbInstance.AContext.TableA.Count();

Comment: @CSharp Here the code: ```DBInstance.Instance.AContext.TableAs.Count()```

Answer (score 1):

I resolve the problem changing the import method.

The first time I imported the models as `Entity Framework Designer from Database`.

Now, importing the models as `Code First from Database` the two models even if have tables with the same name can coexist.